# userRef or createRef returning undefined in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have read lot of answers here but all of them are tide to class components.

If I have simple functional component where I use useRef or createRef, ref.current is undefined
I'm assigning it on top of div or input but I can't get any of their properties

Console.log() gives me data only when I use standelone console.log(ref)
Every other property is undefined e.g. console.log(ref.current)

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const ref = useRef()
  console.log(ref.current) // undefined
  console.log(ref) // { current }

  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <h1 ref={ref}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>      
      {/* <input ref={ref} name="test" value="bla" /> */}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Take a look on this demo and look at console:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-kirch-soe8n

But even in class component I can't access for example ref.current.innerHTML:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-beaver-ic1em

Comment: Because `const ref = useRef()` ref is not defind...
`const ref = useRef('something..')` and then you see 'something..' on the console.
add this: `useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current)
  });`

Comment: yes I have just figure out it. thx

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found where is problem.

If I use useEffect() or if I use some button handler, I have access to element:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(ref.current.innerHTML)
  })
```

same in class component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  myRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.myRef.current); // correct
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.myRef.current); // null

    return <h2 ref={this.myRef}>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
  }
}
```

or

```
<button onClick={()=> console.log(ref.current.innerHTML)}>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You give the ref to the element in the dom, 
so you can't access it before it actually gets render, 
so in react that occur in the component lifecycle,
which is either useEffect or componentDidMount.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
 useEffect(() => {
   console.log(ref.current)
 },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 ref={ref}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {/* <input ref={ref} name="test" value="bla" /> */}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const Expander = forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>test</div>;
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Way without ref and with ref and useState

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function app() {
  const ref = useRef('lalala');
  const [h1Text, setH1Text] = useState('Hello CodeSandbox');

  useEffect(() => { 
    console.log(ref.current)
   });

   const changeHeader = () =>{
    setH1Text('mamamama');
   }
   const changeHeader2 = (ev) =>{
    ev.target.innerHTML = "Hello CodeSandbox222222222222";
   }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 ref={ref} onClick={changeHeader}>{h1Text}</h1>
      <h2 onClick={changeHeader2}>Hello CodeSandbox2</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### And code that input chagne the h1 without refs

```
function Example2() {
  const [h1Text, setH1Text] = useState('Hello CodeSandbox');

   const changeHeader = (ev) =>{
    setH1Text(ev.target.value);
   }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{h1Text}</h1>
      <input onChange={changeHeader} name="test" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you referring component directly without mounting (componentDidMount/useEffect) then you will be get an undefined value. Alternatively you can use arrow function to access ref element.

**example:**

```
export function App(props) {
  const ref = useRef()
  console.log(ref.current) // undefined
  const seeRef = () => {
    console.log(ref.current) // <h1 ></h1>
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1 ref={ref}>Hello React.</h1>
      <button onClick={()=> seeRef()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72548440/4652706