# TypeError: ref.current is undefined (useRef())

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an image and I want to store its dimensions, for placing icons depending of the dimensions. I do so with useRef() hook.

```
const componentRef=useRef()
```

Then I add this `componentRef` to the `<img ref={componentRef}>`. For rendering the icons, I call a function `{setIcons}`.

```
return(
  <div>
    <img ref={componentRef}/>
    {setIcons}
  </div>
)
```

This function again looks like this.

```
const setIcons=(
        props.positions_Reader.map((mac,i)=>(
            <Icon
                style={{
                  position:"absolute",
                  left:componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x,
                  top:componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().y
                }}
            />
        ))
    )
```

The error occurs in this line `left:componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x`

At the first render there is no error, but when I go back and open the component again, this error occurs. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: The ref will be undefined on the first rendering cycle, because your element does not exist yet. Check if `ref.current` is defined and then use what's within it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `componentRef` before it is actually being assigned. Make use of `useEffect` and store the styles in state, this will ensure the re-render when `componentRef.current` changes

```
function App() {
  const componentRef = React.useRef();
  const [style, setStyle] = React.useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    setStyle({
      left: componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x,
      top: componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().y
    })
  }, [componentRef.current])

  const setIcons = props.positions_Reader.map((mac, i) => (
    <Icon
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: style.top + mac.x,
        left: style.left + mac.y
      }}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <img ref={componentRef} />
      {setIcons}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**[Sample Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cqv4tg)**

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. But now in the `setIcons` I want to specify the `<Icon`s position by e.g. `left:componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x+mac.x` (see the last part `+mac.x`). So, that every icon is on its own position. Do you have suggestions for that :)

Answer (score 3):

If we would like to use reference properties of useRef declared component then we should need to wait till component get mount. Before mount it mount if you would like to access it you will get an undefined error.

**Error:**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export function App(props) {

  const ref = useRef()

  console.log(ref.current) // undefined

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1 ref={ref}>Hello React.</h1>
    </div>
  );

}
```

**Solution:**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export function App(props) {

  const ref = useRef()

  const seeRef = () => {
    console.log(ref.current) // <h1 ></h1>
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1 ref={ref}>Hello React.</h1>
      <button onClick={()=> seeRef()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );

}
```