# Invoke child method before invoking child component using react ref

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a method in child component from parent component that displays loading overlay. I am using refs to call the child method. But as I am calling the child method before render function, ref.current is returning undefined.

I followed this question :
[userRef or createRef returning undefined in functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493142/userref-or-createref-returning-undefined-in-functional-component)

I did add ref.current in useEffect but it made no difference. My code looks like:

```
const ParentComponent = ({ actions,...props}) => {

const activeListPageRef = useRef();
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(activeListPageRef.current);
    });


 const getResources = async(resourceIds) => {
        console.log("activeList ref", activeListPageRef);
        if(activeListPageRef.current) {
            activeListPageRef.current.onBtShowLoading();
        }
       //fetch api
      //once done fetching on success hide the loading overlay
     activeListPageRef.current.onBTHide();
}
return (
 < childComponent ref={activeListPageRef} />
)
}

const ChildComponent =({ tableData,  ...props}, ref) => {

const onBtShowLoading = () => {
        gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();
      };
}

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        onGridReady,
        onBtShowLoading,
        onBtHide
    }));
```

How is it possible to refer to child component method before calling the Child component ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the logic that intends to use the ref inside of `useEffect` so that it only runs after the child component is created and the ref is defined.

The code below should work (see [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-ref-question-i0f9m?file=/src/ParentComponent.js:0-607)):

**Child Component**

```
import React, { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from "react";

const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  const onBtShowLoading = () => {
    console.log("onBtShowLoading was called!");
    // Actual implementation here.
  };

  const onBTHide = () => {
    console.log("onBtHide called");
    // Actual implementation here.
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    onBtShowLoading,
    onBTHide
  }));
  return <div>Child Component</div>;
};

export default forwardRef(ChildComponent);
```

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

const ParentComponent = ({ actions, ...props }) => {
  const activeListPageRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    // This code will run after the component renders the first time
    // So activeListPageRef.current will be defined.
    const getResources = async (resourceIds) => {
      if (activeListPageRef.current) {
        activeListPageRef.current.onBtShowLoading();
      }
      activeListPageRef.current.onBTHide();
    };
    // Because useEffect doesn't support async functions directly
    // you have to define the function first, then call it.
    getResources();
  });

  return <ChildComponent ref={activeListPageRef} />;
};
```